# Symfony2 HttpException(422, 'some message') not working

Tags: symfony, httpexception

My problem is the following:

`throw new HttpException(422, "some message")` doesn't work in Controllers.

However, `throw new HttpException(404, "some message")` works, as well as **400** (etc.)

Why can't I throw an `HttpException` with a **422 HTTP status code**?

When I try to, I get a [200] response with the following debug info:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Notice: Undefined offset: **422** in app\cache\dev\classes.php line 3079' in vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\ErrorHandler.php on line 67
>
> ( ! ) ErrorException: Notice: Undefined offset: **422** in app\cache\dev\classes.php line 3079 in vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\ErrorHandler.php on line 67

(I use FOSRESTBundle if it counts...
and of course I cleared the cache)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP status 422 was added only in version 2.1.
The combination of the active debugging with the notice generated by Response::setStatusCode, generates this ugly exception. However it seems that during production there are no problems. However, my advice is **do not use it**.

In my opinion this behavior is unexpected and should be reported..